# What does 'M' means on scipy document?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I love numpy and scipy and often read those documents. For instance, according to the page describing about [numpy.linalg.inv](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html), `inv` takes a parameter of which type is `array_like`.

But, I do not know what  `(..., M, M)` means put before `array_like`. Please let me know what is this.

Comment: Matrix, perhaps? Or looking at the other methods, I think it's the dimensions of the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the operations will be performed for the last two axes of the input array and that the last two axes must be of the same size `M`.

So if you have an input array with 3 axes of shape `n, M, M`, it will return the inverse of the `n` 2D arrays of shape `M, M`, taken from the last 2 axes.

Comment: The use of letters like `M,N` to denote the array's dimensions is common.  But it takes a bit of thinking to realize that's what is going on here.